# JUNG: which libraries are required dependencies?

Tags: java, graph, jung

I'm looking at JUNG for visualizing directed graphs. The JUNG 2.0.1 download comes with 17 different jar files, and some of them appear to be samples and demos.

Does anyone know which are the real libraries that are required if you want to use JUNG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never mind, they're documented in [this wiki page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jung/wiki/JUNG2Basics):

> Following is a list of the primary projects of jung2, along with their dependencies:
>
> - jung-api: the core interfaces that define graphs and their behaviors, plus some utility classes for handling graphs.
>
>   - compile/runtime dependencies: none
> - jung-graph-impl: our implementations of the jung-api interfaces, plus some facilities for generating (random) graphs.
>
>   - compile/runtime dependencies: jung-api, collections-generic
>   - additional unit test dependencies: junit
> - jung-algorithms: classes for analyzing graphs, e.g., clustering, ranking, shortest path calculations, and layout algorithms.
>
>   - compile/runtime dependencies: jung-api, collections-generic, colt
>   - additional unit test dependencies: junit, jung-graph-impl
> - jung-io: classes for saving and storing graphs.
>
>   - compile/runtime dependencies: jung-api, jung-algorithms, collections-generic, colt
>   - additional unit test dependencies: junit, jung-graph-impl
> - jung-visualization: interfaces and classes for rendering graphs as diagrams.
>
>   - compile/runtime dependencies: jung-api, jung-algorithms, colt
> - jung-samples: examples of how to use JUNG.
>
>   - compile/runtimedependencies: jung-api, jung-graph-impl, jung-algorithms, jung-io, jung-visualization

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the dependency list mentioned [in its pom for 2.0.1 version](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jung/jung2/2.0.1/jung2-2.0.1.pom), there shouldn't be any 3rd party dependencies.